How can I change the installation path when reinstalling tomovision_sliceOmatic_5.0_Rev-9?
When I first installed tomovision_sliceOmatic_5.0_Rev-9 in the D:\Program Files folder and then uninstalled it, I tried to install it again and hoped to install it in the C:\Program Files folder.
However, the installer did not allow me to choose the installation path and directly installed it in the D:\Program Files folder. How can I select the folder path for installation?

